# how to mock auth from @react-native-firebase/auth

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, unit-testing, jestjs

I am trying to mock the auth module from the npm library @react-native-firebase/auth however, I keep getting this error back. I have tried mocking it below but obviously it must be incorrect I am just unsure on what is incorrect.

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'credential' of undefined
```

```
jest.mock('@react-native-firebase/auth', () => ({
  auth: {
    GoogleAuthProvider: {
      credential: jest.fn().mockReturnValue('123'),
    },
  },
}));

jest.mock('@react-native-community/google-signin', () => ({
  GoogleSignin: {
    signIn: jest.fn().mockReturnValue('123'),
  },
}));
```

```
    import auth from '@react-native-firebase/auth';
    import {GoogleSignin} from '@react-native-community/google-signin';
    
    export const GoogleLogin = async function (): Promise<void | string> {
      // Get the users ID token
      const {idToken} = await GoogleSignin.signIn();
    
      // Create a Google credential with the token
      const googleCredential = auth.GoogleAuthProvider.credential(idToken);
    
      try {
        auth().signInWithCredential(googleCredential);
      } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
      }
    };
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are mocking `@react-native-firebase/auth` as if it exported `firebase` (where the `auth` namespace is accessed as `firebase.auth`), but you should be mocking it as if it exported the `auth` namespace directly.

In your current mock, you have defined `auth.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.credential` instead of `auth.GoogleAuthProvider.credential`.

```
jest.mock('@react-native-firebase/auth', () => ({
  GoogleAuthProvider: {
    credential: jest.fn().mockReturnValue('123'),
  },
}));
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It's so obvious I should have noticed this!

Answer (score 1):

The existing answers did not cover how to mock `auth().signInWithCredential`. I have updated the answer below.

It used the `default export` of `auth` from `'@react-native-firebase/auth'` and mocked `auth().signInWithCredential()`. However, the correct way is to use the named `export` of `firebase` from `'@react-native-firebase/auth'` and mock `firebase.auth().signInWithCredential()`.

You can see how @react-native-firebase/auth exports the module in this [script](https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/blob/main/packages/auth/lib/index.js)

```
// auth.ts
import auth, { firebase } from '@react-native-firebase/auth'; // THE KEYPOINT HERE
import {GoogleSignin} from '@react-native-community/google-signin';

export const GoogleLogin = async function (): Promise<void | string> {
  // Get the users ID token
  const {idToken} = await GoogleSignin.signIn();

  // Create a Google credential with the token
  const googleCredential = auth.GoogleAuthProvider.credential(idToken);

  try {
    firebase.auth().signInWithCredential(googleCredential); // THIS DID TRICK
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
};
```

---

```
// auth.test.ts
jest.mock('@react-native-firebase/auth', () => ({
  firebase: {
    auth: () => ({
      signInWithCredential: jest.fn(),
  signOut: jest.fn(),
    }),
  },
  GoogleAuthProvider: {
    credential: jest.fn(),
  },
}));

jest.mock('@react-native-google-signin/google-signin', () => {
  return {
    GoogleSignin: {
      signIn: jest
        .fn()
        .mockImplementation(() => Promise.resolve({ idToken: '123' })),
    },
  };
});
```